# Cannot resolve MVC view 'login-form'

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Jan 29 23:34:52 ART 2023

There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

No message available

So, what I am trying to do is overwrite spring's security login template so that I can use a custom one I made.

My IDE (IntelliJ Idea) doesn't recognise the view (nor does spring) however, if I add this line of code

**LoginConfiguration.java**

```
 @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
```

then it works. I would like a way to not overwrite the default resource handlers (because I think it's a bad practice) so both the IDE and Spring can recognise my view.

**Application.properties**

```
server.port=8081
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:XX
spring.datasource.username=Y
spring.datasource.password =Z
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/static/
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/static/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html
```

And here's the method I am trying to make it work

**LoginController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/sarasa")
        public ModelAndView sarasa() {
            var mav = new ModelAndView();
            mav.setViewName("login-form");
            return mav;
        }
```

So I want help on how to make spring boot get the files from src/main/resources/static
I tried resources/WEB-INF, also WEB-INF/classes/, resources/templates/, etc. I am using no template handler (so no thymyleaf or anything and I'd rather not use one since I want to use react later). I also saw lots of post on this site regarding this problem but none of them solved my issue.

Also, here's my login-form.html

**login-form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .login-form {
            width: 340px;
            margin: 50px auto;
            font-size: 15px;
        }
        .login-form form {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            background: #f7f7f7;
            box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
            padding: 30px;
        }
        .login-form h2 {
            margin: 0 0 15px;
        }
        .form-control, .btn {
            min-height: 38px;
            border-radius: 2px;
        }
        .btn {
            font-size: 15px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login-form">
    <form action="/login" method="post">
        <h2 class="text-center">Log in</h2>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Log in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```